# Angular &TypeScript Intellisense does not work inside of *ngFor statements

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, stackblitz

I have the the following simplified scenario ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay2xyk))  where the code compiles and shows well and intellisense works as expected for the first level of ngFor statement. for some reason, however, the second ngFor statment does not provide any intellisense support and I wonder if this can be fixed. 
the same applies for stackblitz and VS Code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div>
        <!-- intellisense working well here -->
        {{ item.name }}
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems" style="margin-left: 25px;">
        <div>
            <!-- intellisense not working here -->
            {{ subItem. }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```